# Implementing interface ServiceConnection

Tags: java, android, generics, interface, abstract-class

**Step #1.** Required to implement the interface [`ServiceConnection`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ServiceConnection.html):

```
public class ServiceBinding<T extends ParentService<T>> implements ServiceConnection {
    public T bindedService;

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        // Warning: Type safety: Unchecked cast from IBinder to ChatService<T>.LocalBinder
        bindedService = ((T.LocalBinder) service).getService();
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
    }
}
```

**Step #2.** Then the **Parent-service** will be as follows:

```
public abstract class ParentService<T extends ParentService<T>> extends Service {
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public T getService() {
            return (T) T.this; // Warning: Unchecked cast from ChatService<T> to T
        }
    };
}
```

**Question:** Is such a solution acceptable?

How should the [`ServiceConnection`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ServiceConnection.html) be properly implemented?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement like this -

```
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
        service = binder.getService();
        boundVal = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        boundVal = false;
    }
};
```

The boundVal is the trigger for 'unbindservice'. Pass on boundval with connection as the parameter.

`onServiceConnected()` and `onServiceDisconnected()` are called once the client-server connection has been established or disconnected respectively. In the case of the `onServiceConnected()` method, this will be passed an `IBinder` object containing the information needed by the client to interact with the service.
Cheers!

Comment: The question of how to make a generalized implementation of the binding in order to avoid duplication of code.